# How can I get the longitude and latitude in my android app?

Tags: java, android, location

I've been trying to get the `location` for the particular  phone for a while now. I have used the following code but instead of showing the location it will just crash when I try and run the app in my emulator.

Once I've got the longitude and latitude I am going to use it to map the current location on a google map!

```
public class Homescreen extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {
    final TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homescreen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int latitude = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int longitude = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        t.setText(latitude);

//      Log.i("Geo_Location", "Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude);

    }
```

Comment: check this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/

Answer (score 0):

Use This Activity. I hope it will help you.

```
   package yourPackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.infologitech.spotways.constants.SpotwaysSettingsKeys.SettingDefaultValue;
import com.infologitech.spotways.constants.SpotwaysSettingsKeys.SettingKey;
import com.infologitech.spotways.custom.TransactionSupport;

public class GetCurrentLocationActivity extends Activity implements
        LocationListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Context context = this;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Location mLocation;
    private float minAccuracy = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        mLocationClient.connect();
        //waitForLocation();
}else finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(5f);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {
            int latitude = (int) (loc.getLatitude());
        int longitude = (int) (loc.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this,"Lat "+latitude+", Lng "+longitude);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopUpdate();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void stopUpdate() {
        try {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            mLocationClient.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public  boolean checkPlayServices() {
        final int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                        resultCode, context, 3434);
                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.show();
                    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            if (ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID == resultCode) {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```